# Scrollbar in python tkinter Toplevel() shows up but does not scroll

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, scrollbar

I have looked through all the answered questions available here but to no avail. I'm working on Mac OS X High Sierra and my Scrollbar widget shows up but doesn't scroll the window, any advice?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x500')
root.resizable(False, False) 


def window():

    popup = Toplevel()

    vertScrollbar = Scrollbar(popup, orient='vertical')
    vertScrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    scrollCanvas = Canvas(popup, width='400', height='500', yscrollcommand=vertScrollbar.set)

    vertScrollbar.config(command=scrollCanvas.yview)

    scrollFrame = Frame(scrollCanvas, width='400', height='500') 
    scrollCanvas.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollFrame, anchor='n')

    for words in range(150):
        test = Label(scrollCanvas)
        test.config(text='this is a test')
        test.pack()

    scrollCanvas.config(scrollregion=scrollCanvas.bbox('all'))
#scrollCanvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,400,800)) doesn't work either
    scrollCanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both')
    scrollFrame.pack(side='top', fill='both')

openWindow = Button(root, text='Push Me', command=window)
openWindow.pack(ipadx='5', ipady='3', pady='10')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inside `scrollFrame`.

The labels are packed in `popup`, not in `scrollCanvas`

The `scrollCanvas.config(scrollregion=scrollCanvas.bbox('all'))` doesn't seem to do the job, not clear as to why.

Here is an example that works for Python 3.6.5 on windows 10:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root.resizable(False, False) 

vertScrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
vertScrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

scrollCanvas = Canvas(root, width='400', height='500',
                      scrollregion=(0, 0, 400, 500),
                      yscrollcommand=vertScrollbar.set)

vertScrollbar.config(command=scrollCanvas.yview)

scrollCanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both')

img = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
scrollCanvas.create_image(2, 2, anchor='nw', image = img)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It must be a Mac OS and Python issue because it still doesn't work, there's no errors or anything it just doesn't move the canvas frame. Thanks for the reply though! Putting the labels in the right window was definitely a step in the right direction :)

Comment: _"doesn't seem to do the job, not clear as to why."_ - it is because `bbox` only counts canvas items -- objects created by one of the `create_*` methods. It doesn't know anything about widgets added to a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

Comment: Thank you for that nugget Bryan.