# tkinter labels disappear when scrolling

Tags: tkinter, label, scrollbar

The labels disappear when I scroll vertically slowly.  If I scroll quickly or use the scroll wheel the labels come back.  The labels also come back if I resize the window.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Below is the code.

I am trying to update by binding to the configure event.  Have tried binding to the frame and scroll bar but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Here is a link to video showing what is happening.

https://youtu.be/VrsNbgA9dms

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()


root.wm_title('Scroll Bar Test')

inv_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
inv_window.title("Frame.grid")

#this array will hold widgets
inv_widgets = []

#create main Frame in toplevel window
inv_frame_main = tk.Frame(inv_window, bg="gray")
inv_frame_main.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

#create Canvas for scroll bars
inv_canvas = tk.Canvas(inv_frame_main, bg="gray")
inv_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns')


inv_frame_main.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
inv_frame_main.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#This is the Vertical scrollbar
inv_vsb = tk.Scrollbar(inv_frame_main, orient="vertical", command=inv_canvas.yview)
inv_vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

#This is Horizontal scrollbar
inv_hsb = tk.Scrollbar(inv_frame_main, orient="horizontal", command=inv_canvas.xview)
inv_hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky ='ew')

inv_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=inv_vsb.set)
inv_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=inv_hsb.set)


#this is Frame inside the canvas that will hold labels, using create_window because Brian Oakley said so
frame_buttons = tk.Frame(inv_canvas, bg="gray")
inv_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor="nw")



for k in range(1,10) :
    current_pt_row = []
    current_inv_row = []
    for l in range(2):
        if l == 1:
            
            inv_label = tk.Label(frame_buttons, borderwidth = 2, relief = tk.RIDGE)
            inv_label.grid(row=k, column=l, sticky="nsew", padx=3, pady=3)
            inv_cable = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Cable "+str(k), bg="White")
            inv_cable.grid(row=k, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
            current_inv_row.append(inv_label)
    
    
    
    inv_widgets.append(current_inv_row)

inv_window.update_idletasks()
inv_canvas.configure(scrollregion=inv_canvas.bbox("all"))
    

def onFrameConfigure(event):
    inv_canvas.configure(scrollregion=inv_canvas.bbox("all"))
    inv_window.update_idletasks()
inv_vsb.bind("<Configure>", onFrameConfigure)

m = 0 
for x in inv_widgets:
    part_id = tk.Label(x[0], bg="White", text=m, relief=tk.RIDGE)
    part_id.grid(column=m, row=1, sticky="nesw")
    ser_num = tk.Label(x[0], bg="White", text=m, relief=tk.RIDGE)
    ser_num.grid(column=m, row=2, sticky="nesw")
    m = m + 2
            


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you don't define `root`.

Comment: _"using create_window because Brian Oakley said so"_ - that's not a good reason. You should strive to understand why, and not just do it because I said so. If you're creating a vertical stack of widgets with a determinate size, you don't really need the internal frame - you could just place the widgets directly in the canvas with some very easy math to compute the coordinates of each group of widgets.

Comment: hi Brian, Sorry, I was trying to be funny.  I got this from the comment you made on another post,. "It doesn't know anything about widgets added to a canvas with pack, place, or grid. – Bryan Oakley May 8 '18 at 12:07"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230309/scrollbar-in-python-tkinter-toplevel-shows-up-but-does-not-scroll        I will get rid of internal frame.